# How to remove hard coded values from JSP and achieve redirection in one line of code?

Tags: java, jsp, security, config

I am trying to remove the hardcode name from JSP file. I need to give the names in Config file and call in the jsp so that when a user does view page source he should not see the names.
How can I do it in JSP.

My code:

```
 if (((tech == 'google.com') && ((id == 'email') || id == 'domain'))) || ((tech == 'google') && id == 'test')))
        window.location = (url.substring(0, res + 5) + ("google/") + url.substring(res + 5, url.length));
```

now how to remove the hardcoded values and give it in the config file and call it here so that when I view page source I should not see google.com names

My New Code try:

```
 Config.properties
 envs=google.com,yahho.com
 name= google,yahoo
 tokenurl=google/,yahoo/

 sample.jsp

 <%@ page import = "java.util.ResourceBundle" %>

 <% ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");
 String names=resource.getString("name");
 String env=resource.getString("envs");
 String turls=resource.getString("tokenurl");
 %>

 if (((tech == env[0]) && ((id == 'email') || id == 'domain'))) || ((tech 
 == 'names[0]') && id == 'test')))
 window.location = (url.substring(0, res + 5) + ("turls[0]") + 
 url.substring(res + 5, url.length));
 else if (((tech == env[1]) && ((id == 'email') || id == 'domain'))) || 
 ((tech == 'names[1]') && id == 'test')))
    window.location = (url.substring(0, res + 5) + ("turls[1]") + 
  url.substring(res + 5, url.length));
```

But I am not sure this is a proper way of writing code. Can anyone suggest a proper standard way I could follow to achieve in just one line of if condition?

Comment: if my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: That is javascript, `tech` and `id` must be there in a form on the java side, and setting the window.location could imply a forward/redirect to another page. Rather hard to understand what you want to achieve. Explain a little.

Comment: @JoopEggen, You are right I am trying to achieve where the condition is if the name is google I need to redirect them to Google/ page and if the name is yahoo I need to redirect to yahoo/ page. How can I achieve this in JSP? but in my JSP code i should not hardcode the values of names.

Comment: @JoopEggen, Could you please highlight some suggestion on how to rewrite the code without hardcoding and achieve redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classical JSP. Here I use `%><%` so still no output is written, and one can redirect to another page.

- HTTP sends first some header lines, and one empty line and then optional HTML content.
  Doing a redirect would be a header line. So still no content has to be written by the JSP. A header line can state the character set/encoding used, cookies, and so on.

So:

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.ResourceBundle"
%><%
   ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");
   String names = resource.getString("name");
   String[] env = resource.getString("envs").split(",\\s*");
   String turls = resource.getString("tokenurl");

   String tech = request.getParameter("tech");
   if (tech != null && tech.equals("google")) {
       String url = response.encodeRedirectURL(env[13]);
       response.sendRedirect(url); // Just tell the browser to redirect, load the url.
       return;
   }
%>
```

Unfortunately the actual logic is your affair. In contrast to JavaScript's `s == 'abc'` one has `s.equals("abc")`.

Learning and using JSP tags and the EL, expression language, will make the code smaller.

Using a servlet as *controller*, to prepare data and then forward to any JSP as *view*, parametrised with the data (or redirect to some external URL), the *model*, would be even nicer.

Comment: Thanks! But I do not want to show the user google and if I want to check other names as well and navigate respectively, should this be added with another if condition for another name

Comment: That is programming; what you have as data and what you want to do on those data. _I_, I cannot tell; you probably have a kind of lookup in your `config.properties` with keys that match possible request parameter. And all those cases, ifs should not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property file in the package with extension '.properties' and use those properties defined in the file in jsp by importing the resource bundle package in the jsp.

**config.properties**

```
name=priya
email=priya@gmail.com
phone=22222
```

**sample.jsp**

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.ResourceBundle" %>

 <% ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");
    String name=resource.getString("name");
    String email=resource.getString("email");
    String phone=resource.getString("phone");
     %>

    Name:  <input type="text" id="name" value="<%=name %>">
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" value="<%=email %>">
    Phone: <input type="text" id="phone" value="<%=phone %>">
```

Comment: Thanks! AbhiN , but my expectation was to achieve Url Navigation by getting the name from config.properties.I want to use in the condition that I have given.